# Rewritepath not working in case of subsites (Sharepoint 2013)

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint

I have created a webservice inorder to sync task with outlook by referring - http://syncspviewoutlook.codeplex.com/. 
(This functionality basically syncs current user task with outlook instead of syncing all tasks, whenever connect to Outlook is clicked for a Task List)

I have created an httpmodule inorder to rewritepath (lists.asmx) with  path customservice.asmx  instead of Global.asax file which works fine for parent site(http://example:8081/)
Below is the code for calling my custom webservice.

public void context_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

```
            HttpContext ctx = HttpContext.Current;
            if (ctx != null)
            {
                string path = ctx.Request.Url.AbsolutePath;
                string userAgent = ctx.Request.UserAgent;
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(userAgent))
                {
                    if (userAgent.Contains("Microsoft Office Outlook") && path.ToLower().IndexOf("_vti_bin/lists.asmx") >= 0)
                    {
                        ctx.RewritePath("/_layouts/15/folder/customservice.asmx");
                    }
                }
            }

    }
```

But when I try to sync tasks in my subsite the rewritepath doesnot seem to work and it is not even throwing any Error. It doesnot call the new customservice.asmx url even though it hits the line - (ctx.RewritePath("/_layouts/15/folder/customservice.asmx");)

Any idea as in why is the original lists.asmx is called and not the new one for subsites(http://example:8081/subsite1/). I did enable Tracing but was unable to find any error.

Answer (score 0):

Was able to resolve the above issue.. as answered here https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/cf58fa8d-2806-4732-a556-5996a86d5c10/rewritepath-not-working-in-case-of-subsites?forum=sharepointdevelopment

I had to change my call from BeginRequest to PostResolveRequestCache